# Why is WaitForSingleObject() considering the supplied handle to be invalid?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, stdin, filehandle, waitforsingleobject

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to work on a Win32 app that attempts to read from stdin.  It retrieves a valid handle from GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE) and immediately calls WaitForSingleObject() with the handle as a parameter, but the return value is always WAIT_FAILED. I have verified that the value of the file handle is 01, which is odd bc stdin is usually 0, stdout 1, and stderr 2, so this is probably an important clue.

When I used the "Error Lookup" tool the code (6) means that the handle is invalid.  In the VS output window I get "WAIT_FAILED. GetLastError() returned: 6" from the code below.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
   hStdIn = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
   XTrace (L"hStdIn: %ul\r\n", hStdIn );
   if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hStdIn)
   {
        INPUT_RECORD inputRecord[512];
        DWORD nNumBytesRead;
        switch ( WaitForSingleObject( hStdIn, 1000 ) )
        {
            case( WAIT_TIMEOUT ):
                XTrace (L"WAIT_TIMEOUT\r\n" );
                break; // return from this function to allow thread to terminate
            case( WAIT_OBJECT_0 ):
                // clear events
                ReadConsoleInput( hStdIn, inputRecord, 512, &nNumBytesRead );
                XTrace (L"Called ReadConsoleInput(). WAIT_OBJECT_0\r\n" );
                break;
            case( WAIT_FAILED ):
                XTrace (L"WAIT_FAILED. GetLastError() returned: %d\r\n", GetLastError() );
                break;
            case( WAIT_ABANDONED ): 
                XTrace (L"WAIT_ABANDONED\r\n" );
                break;
            default:
                XTrace (L"Unexpected result from WaitForSingleObject\r\n" );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works fine when I try it, hard to guess.  Are you redirecting input?   Then you get NULL to indicate failure, not INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.  Your error check is wrong.

Comment: 01 is not a valid handle.

Comment: That "0 for stdin" thing is for file descriptors.  Handles aren't the same thing.

Comment: @Hans, Raymond and Harry, see my comment below.  I think I was hasty in seeking another solution.  But I'm grateful for your suggestions.

Comment: Well, nobody is ever going to learn something from this Q+A.   Bah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetStdHandle` says:

> The handle has GENERIC_READ and GENERIC_WRITE access rights

`WaitForSingleObject` says:

> The handle must have the SYNCHRONIZE access right.

Comment: How would someone establish SYNCHRONIZE access rights for the stdin handle?

Comment: In reading the comments on `WaitForSingleObject` on MSDN, I'm not sure it is going to work the way you want, but you can try it: You can obtain different permissions by creating a new `HANDLE` via `DuplicateHandle`.

Comment: @Alyoshak, did that actually work?  Because if this was the problem I think you should have received error code 5 (access denied) rather than error 6 (invalid handle).

Comment: @Harry, I credited Dark Falcon bc after reading the docs I found his answer convincing on its face. Perhaps I should've verified it.  As things are bc of time demands I abandoned WaitForSingleObject() and moved to C-style reading from stdin.  Simpler. In order to prove that lack of the SYNCHRONIZE access right was the problem I would've had to use CreateHandle() instead of GetStdHandle() and then dive into the OVERLAPPED mess.